# Is There any possible answer to get the same output of these code

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
select e.Name, m.Name as 'Manager Id'
FROM Employee e
left outer join Employee m on e.ManagerId = m.EmployeeId
```

In this code I Used the left outer join to get my desired output.
the code below is also showing the same output as above.

```
select e.Name, (Select m.name from Employee m where m.EmployeeId = e.ManagerId) as 'Manager Name'
From Employee e
```

I would like to know if there is any other possible code to get the same output of these code?
By the way, my table consist of 3 columns, EmployeeId, Name, ManagerId.

```
EmpId  |   Name | ManagerId
1      |Charlie    | 2
2      |Mike       | 3
3      |Jayr       |
4      |Ivan       | 3
5      |Franz      | 3
6      |Alexis     | 2
```

The managerID it is also the EmpID. Like in Charlie, the manager of Charlie is Mike because It's empID is 2 and charlie's manageriD is 2, it is also same in the others,
Below is the output of the codes above.

```
EmployeeName | ManagerName
Charlie       |  Mike
Mike          |  Jayr
Jayr          |  NULL
Ivan          |  Jayr
Franz         |  Jayr
Alexis        |  Mike
```

Comment: Your left join query is clear and straightforward, just the one for the job (so I agree with @Philip Kelley completely). Are you actually concerned with the performance you get from either of the two queries? Or are you indeed merely interested in finding the alternatives? If the former, you should ask about the real issue. If the latter, what would be the point of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example with recursive CTE. [more info about CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
;WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT EmpId, Name, ManagerId, CAST(ManagerId AS nvarchar(10)) AS ManagerName
 FROM dbo.Employee
 WHERE ManagerId IS NULL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT e.EmpId, e.Name, e.ManagerId, c.Name
 FROM dbo.Employee e JOIN cte c ON e.ManagerId = c.EmpId
 )
 SELECT Name, ManagerName
 FROM cte
 ORDER BY EmpId
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9df4a/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

Your first version, the left outer join, is as concise and succinct as it gets. There are probably more ways to write this query, using CTEs, subqueries, unions, I don't know what, but for my money all they'd do is layer on poinltess complexity.